# vpn conntect over an additional server

Tags: ubuntu, xen, vpn

I (A) want to connect to my virtual XEN-server (B) with Ubuntu OS via vpn. This server (B) should than connect to another server (C). The traffic should be routed from A to C. C is using CISCO VPN.  But how do I do that? Is there a howto that I can read?
Thanks for y'all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by routing the second VPN over the first. Lets say we have a VPN with the gw 192.168.10.1 and a second VPN with the server address 10.10.1.1 than we have to set a route for the second one with `route -n add 10.10.1.1 192.168.10.1` (Do not set a setting that sends all traffic over the first VPN!).
Now we can tell the OS with the routing table which VPN to use. Let us we want to connect 192.168.3.4 over the first VPN and 10.10.2.2 over the second. We use `route -n add 192.168.3.4 192.168.10.1` and `route -n add 10.10.2.2 10.10.1.1` etc.